# Android - LocalBroadcast

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot but didn't find the solution to the following issue.

**Context :**

- I use an AsyncHttpResponseHandler object to handle all my webservice
  responses
- If I get a particular error code from the WS, I want to show an alert dialog (whatever the activity currently displayed)
- I came to think that using the LocalBroadcastManager would be a good solution  as the HTTP handler is not aware of the currently displayed activity

**Problem :**
After implementation of all what seems to be needed to make it work, my intent sent from the async handler is not received.

**Additional note :**

- the ApplicationContext is stored in my StaticItems
  class which contains all the static data I need in my app.It is setup via a custom class which inherits from Application
- If I broadcast the intent from an activity, the OnReceive event is triggered

I thank you in advance for any help you could provide.

Cheers !

Here are some pieces of my code :

**The code in the http handler**

```
public class AsyncResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        if(response != null && response.length > 0) {
            CrvData data = JsonHelper.getCrvData(new String(response));
            String code = data.getErrorCode();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(code) && code.equals(StaticItems.C_WS_OBSOLETE_VERSION_ERROR)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(StaticItems.BROADCAST_INTENT_MESSAGE);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(data.getValue()));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(StaticItems.applicationContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**The code of the root Activity I use for all my activities** :

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * The local broadcast receiver
     */
    protected MyBroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        filter.addAction(StaticItems.BROADCAST_INTENT_MESSAGE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(StaticItems.applicationContext).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(StaticItems.applicationContext).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }
}
```

**The receiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
                .setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.dlg_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert_holo_light)
                .setMessage(R.string.dlg_app_is_obsolete)
                .setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.dlg_yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is  `MainActivity ` still running while you send the broadcast?

Comment: Have you considered an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)?

Comment: @Boss As the current displayed activity is a MainActivity (as all the activities in my app), yes it is

Comment: @Knossos nope I wasn't aware of this project. I'll look a it. Though, I would like to understand why my code is not working

Comment: From which part of your `MainActivity` code you are sending the broadcast, can you tell us that?

Comment: You know for sure that onReceive is not called? Or you just don't see the dialog coming?

Comment: @Boss The broadcast can be sent from many places. There are http calls from some onResume of an activity or after a user action (click event, mainly)

Comment: @mvai for sure. I put a breakpoint in the onReceive method of the receiver. Furthermore, as mentioned, If I send the broadcast from the activity, the onReceive is triggered.

Comment: If you are sending the broadcast from an activity the `onReceive` is called. Then from where else are you sending that now? I didn't understand that..

Comment: @Boss I edited my post. The declaration of the AsyncResponseHandler class (partially but enough of it) has beed added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so... I figured out that the intent was not received because of this line : 
`intent.setData(Uri.parse(data.getValue()));`

And as @mvai pointed, the dialog cannot be displayed from the application context. I managed to get the current activity by having a reference to it in my application class. (I checked out to be sure for not having any memory leak)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, for some reason you can not `setData(..)` on Intent returned via LocalBroadcastManager, when I placed my URI in the extra data, it started to work.... possibly a bug?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `context` you are using is not an activity context and thus can't be used for creating dialogs.

Namely, the context that is passed to `onReceive` in this case should be your application context, `StaticItems.applicationContext`, which is *not* good for showing dialogs.

If this is the case, you should somehow rearrange your code to make sure to pass an activity context rather than the application one.

Comment: I understand your guess but the thing is no breakpoint inside the onReceive is reached. As a result I don't think this is the problem

Comment: So your question should be: why `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(appContext).sendBroadcast(intent)` works when called from activity and doesn't work when called from another class. I actually see no difference between the two, so there should be another error somewhere (`if` clauses in the onSuccess?). As for the dialog not showing, I'm pretty sure it is a `Context` issue. It is well documented that dialog builder works only with activity contexts.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I haven't done a copy/paste. After looking at the differences, I found out the issus (answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `addCategory()` from your `IntentFilter`

was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650832/cannot-receive-broadcast-in-activity-from-localbroadcastmanager-in-intentservice)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it is not working either. As mentioned by the OP in a comment : _the IntentFilter instance and the Intent instance should have the same category. I modify the code to use the same category for IntentFilter and it works great._